# Theorem Proving in Idris

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I was reading [Idris tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/theorems.html). And I can't understand the following code.

```
disjoint : (n : Nat) -> Z = S n -> Void
disjoint n p = replace {P = disjointTy} p ()
  where
    disjointTy : Nat -> Type
    disjointTy Z = () 
    disjointTy (S k) = Void
```

So far, what I figure out is ...
`Void` is the empty type which is used to prove something is impossible.

replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y
replace uses an equality proof to transform a predicate.

My questions are:

1. which one is an equality proof? (Z = S n)?
2. which one is a predicate? the `disjointTy` function?
3. What's the purpose of `disjointTy`? Does disjointTy Z = () means Z is in one Type "land" () and (S k) is in another land `Void`?
4. In what way can an Void output represent contradiction?

Ps. What I know about proving is "all things are no matched then it is false." or "find one thing that is contradictory"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which one is an equality proof? (Z = S n)?

The `p` parameter is the equality proof here. `p` has type `Z = S n`.

> which one is a predicate? the `disjointTy` function?

Yes, you are right.

> What's the purpose of `disjointTy`?

Let me repeat the definition of `disjointTy` here:

```
disjointTy : Nat -> Type
disjointTy Z = ()
disjointTy (S k) = Void
```

The purpose of `disjointTy` is to be that predicate `replace` function needs. This consideration determines the type of `disjointTy`, viz. `[domain] -> Type`. Since we have equality between naturals numbers, `[domain]` is `Nat`.

To understand how the body has been constructed we need to take a look at `replace` one more time:

```
replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y
```

Recall that we have `p` of `Z = S n`, so `x` from the above type is `Z` and `y` is `S n`. To call `replace` we need to construct a term of type `P x`, i.e. `P Z` in our case. This means the type `P Z` returns must be easily constructible, e.g. the unit type is the ideal candidate for this. We have justified `disjointTy Z = ()` clause of the definition of `disjointTy`. Of course it's not the only option, we could have used any other inhabited (non-empty) type, like `Bool` or `Nat`, etc.

The return value in the second clause of `disjointTy` is obvious now -- we want `replace` to return a value of `Void` type, so `P (S n)` has to be `Void`.

Next, we use `disjointTy` like so:

```
replace   {P = disjointTy}   p    ()
           ^                 ^    ^
           |                 |    |
           |                 |    the value of `()` type
           |                 |
           |                 proof term of Z = S n 
           |
           we are saying "this is the predicate"
```

As a bonus, here is an alternative proof:

```
disjoint : (n : Nat) -> Z = S n -> Void
disjoint n p = replace {P = disjointTy} p False
  where
    disjointTy : Nat -> Type
    disjointTy Z = Bool
    disjointTy (S k) = Void
```

I have used `False`, but could have used `True` -- it doesn't matter. What matters is our ability to construct a term of type `disjointTy Z`.

> In what way can an Void output represent contradiction?

`Void` is defined like so:

```
data Void : Type where
```

It has no constructors! There is no way to create a term of this type whatsoever (under some conditions: like Idris' implementation is correct and the underlying logic of Idris is sane, etc.). So if some function claims it can return a term of type `Void` there must be something fishy going on. Our function says: if you give me a proof of `Z = S n`, I will return a term of the *empty* type. This means `Z = S n` cannot be constructed in the first place because it leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, `p : x = y` is an equality proof. So `p` is a equality proof and `Z = S k` is a equality type.
2. Also yes, usually any `P : a -> Type` is called predicate, like `IsSucc : Nat -> Type`. In boolean logic, a predicate would map `Nat` to true or false. Here, a predicate holds, if we can construct a proof for it. And it is true, if we can construct it (`prf : ItIsSucc 4`). And it is false, if we cannot construct it (there is no member of `ItIsSucc Z`).
3. At the end, we want `Void`. Read the `replace` call as `Z = S k -> disjointTy Z -> disjointTy (S k)`, that is `Z = S K -> () -> Void`. So replace needs two arguments: the proof `p : Z = S k` and the unit `() : ()`, and voilà, we have a void. By the way, instead of `()` you could use any type that you can construct, e.g. `disjointTy Z = Nat` and then use `Z` instead of `()`.
4. In dependent type theory we construct proofs like `prf : IsSucc 4`. We would say, we have a proof `prf` that `IsSucc 4` is true. `prf` is also called a witness for `IsSucc 4`. But with this alone we could only proove things to be true. This is the definiton for `Void`:

   `data Void : Type where`

   There is no constructor. So we cannot construct a witness that `Void` holds. If you somehow ended up with a `prf : Void`, something is wrong and you have a contradiction.